# Table Per Hierarchy - Id unique per sub-class

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Given the example at http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-inheritance.html

I have a base class Party and two concrete classes (Company, Person)

I would like to use Table Per Hierachy (Single Table), but my ids are only unique per concrete type.

i.e. Company and Person may have matching Id's

Is there any way to include the discriminator value in the Id as a composite id?
But still be able to call Get<>(id)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this (Fluent):

```
public class PartyMap : ClassMap<Party>
{      
    public PartyMap()
    {
          Table("Parties");             
          CompositeId<CompositeIdType>(x => x.Id)
            .KeyProperty(x => x.IdCompositePart)
            .KeyProperty(x => x.Discriminator);
          DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("Discriminator");
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyway to set it up so I can still call Get with just the IdCompositePart?

Comment: I don't think is possible.  Get uses the entity's identifier.  The identifier needs to be defined in the superclass and must be shared with all the subclasses.  If you don't share the identifier between your entities may be you don't need inheritance at all.